# set the date of kendodatepicker using knockout-kendo

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

How to set date to today + 1 month i.e if today is
 11/12/2013, then set to 12/12/2013 using knockout-kendo

Like the today's date is set as below
       self.todaysDate = ko.observable(new Date());
 how to set this one based on todaysDate
       self.nextDate = ko.observable(?????);

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    this.one = ko.observable(now);
    this.two = ko.observable(new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate()));
};
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/F3VHE/

If you are doing a lot of work with dates, I would recommend checking out http://momentjs.com/ as well.